# What is the best way to do a slideshow on a website with pictures from a folder?

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I have to make a slideshow on a website with few confines. The pictures must come from a folder and pictures are uploaded at any time so it has to be autonomous and load new pictures without breaking the slideshow.

Do you know what language should I use, is there a library that already do that ?

I searched on google and I found nothing really interesting.

Thank you :)

Comment: You may use Javascript to display the images in your site, and PHP to get the images from the server. Look for **slideshow** at GitHub, you will find many of them.

Comment: Thank you, I found few solutions on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [**E2 Photo Gallery**](http://www.e2interactive.com/e2_photo_gallery/) can get dynamicly pictures from a folder.

But here is two solutions without a library :

- By using Javascript and PHP : **[Dynamically populating a JavaScript image slideshow](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml)**
- Or with JQuery and PHP : **[Read All Images from a folder And display slide show.](https://gist.github.com/aslan144/2047603)**